# How to set proxy to android emulator using command line?

Tags: android-emulator

I am able to bring up the emulator(Android SDK 4.0.3) with proxy setting from the command line and The browser able to find the site, but the page is not loading properly.

```
emulator -avd myavd -http-proxy=http://abc-proxy.xyz.com:8080
```

Answer (score 6):

Use below steps -

1.Right click Project -> Run As -> Run Configure -> Target

2.Scroll Down

3.Additional emulator command line option, type

```
-http-proxy http://10.1.1.10:8080
```

4.Restart ur emulator, it will work, and it is working for me too

Answer (score 2):

Remove = & put .avd and try so it becomes

emulator -avd myavd.avd -http-proxy http://abc-proxy.xyz.com:8080

Answer (score 1):

maybe it needs username and password, you can type

```
emulator -avd myavd -http-proxy username:password@abc-proxy.xyz.com:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Add proxy using command mode

```
 Step 1 ( go to emulator directory )
 cd /Users/$(whoami)/Library/Android/sdk/emulator

 Step 2 ( Get all list of Advs  ) 
 emulator -list-avds

 Step 3 ( Execute Command )
 emulator -avd <emulator name> -http-proxy http://<local-ip-address>:<port>

 Example: 
 emulator -avd nexus_01 -http-proxy http://abc-proxy.xyz.com:8080
```